# fill div height on the browser no matter its content

Tags: html, css

I have see similar question about this but...

I want fill the green div to take 100% of the browser no matter its content.

http://jsbin.com/aculed/1/edit

HTML:

```
  <div id="container">

            <div id="yellow">
                    left 
            </div> 

            <div id="green">
                    right              

              <p>bla bla</p><p>bla bla</p> <p>bla bla</p><p>bla bla</p> 
            </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

body, html {

```
            height:100%;
            background-color:grey;
    }

    #container {

            width:90%;
            background-color:white;
    } 

    #yellow {
            float:left;
            width:30%;
            background-color:yellow;
    }

    #green {
       height:100%;
            height:auto;
            margin-left: 50%;
            background-color:green;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Following should give you what you need (http://jsbin.com/osiviq/1/):

```
        body, html {
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                height:100%;
                background-color:grey;
        }

        #container {
                width:90%;
                background-color:white;
        } 

        #yellow {
                float:left;
                width:30%;
                background-color:yellow;
        }

        #green {
                height: 100%;
                position:relative;
                margin-left: 50%;
                background-color:green;
        }
```

**Update:** Add the following at the top of your css (Copied this from one of my old sites):

```
html, ADDRESS, APPLET, AREA, A, BASE, BASEFONT, BIG, BLOCKQUOTE, BODY, BR, B, CAPTION, CENTER, CITE, CODE, DD, DFN, DIR, div, DL, DT, EM, FONT, FORM, H1, H2, H3, H4, H5, H6, HEAD, HR, HTML, IMG, INPUT, ISINDEX, I, KBD, LINK, LI, MAP, MENU, META, OL, OPTION, PARAM, PRE, P, SAMP, SCRIPT, SELECT, SMALL, STRIKE, STRONG, STYLE, SUB, SUP, TABLE, TD, TEXTAREA, TH, TITLE, TR, TT, UL, U, VAR {
    margin:0px;
    border:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

Comment: look http://jsbin.com/osiviq/10 , it dont work if you add content. Try to scroll, you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Please add the updated style at the top of your css file/ style block.  Don't ask me where I got that from, I copied it from one of my very old sites :)

Comment: Remove the height: from the green div, and add height: 100% to the container div.  [jsbin.com/osiviq/19/](http://jsbin.com/osiviq/19) seems to do what you want.

Comment: @Joe It seems I have to replace in the green div the height:100%; to min-height:100%; and not just remove it.

Comment: Hey, That button? what's that??? that's crazy, how did you do it? it's JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about scrolling when the length is taller than the screen, use min-height:100%:

```
#green {
    min-height:100%;
    margin-left: 50%;
    background-color:green;
}
```

Edit: Firefox also requires 100% height on all parent divs up to the body:

```
#container {
    height:100%;
    width:90%;
    margin:0;padding:0;
    background-color:white;
}
```

Comment: yeah, but in that case, I return to problem number one. http://jsbin.com/osiviq/12

Comment: I thought there only was one problem (getting the green div to always fill the full height). Also, what browser? I noticed that Firefox also requires the container div to have a height:100%; http://jsbin.com/osiviq/14/edit

Comment: Yeah, Firefox. now it work with http://jsbin.com/osiviq/14/ . Thank you. this will make the test easier http://jsbin.com/osiviq/24/edit ... though I don't know who initially got that idea to put that button their :)

Comment: The white container [in the first post ](http://jsbin.com/aculed/1/) is not filled in your solution  jsbin.com/osiviq/14/ .

Comment: You changed the #container background color to this: "background-color:bl;". Change it back to "White" and it works.

Comment: Well that's what I did but if you scroll, you'll see that the white div is not filled, check here: http://jsbin.com/osiviq/34/

Comment: If you want the white div to always take up the full height too, change it's height to min-height:100% as well: http://jsbin.com/osiviq/36

Comment: Yeah but the problem their is: the green div is not filled to the browser if there is no content in it. like what happen here http://jsbin.com/osiviq/37/

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things going on here:

1. The default "height" on an element is auto*
2. When the height of a "parent" element (body, html) is auto, the resulting height is calculated based on the natural heights of the children*
3. Height "100%" on a child will search for an **explicit** parent height.
4. If all parents of the element have an automatic or percentage height, `height:100%` is functionally ignored.*

The exception to this is when you give an element absolute or fixed positioning. These will calculate widths, heights, and positions for the outermost element based on the viewport*; absolutely positioned children will have their position calculated based on their absolutely positioned parent*. 
Say *that* five times really fast.

Basically, you can manage what you want by giving  your container (and any children that you want to stretch)  `position:absolute;` and doing some fiddling.

It will probably spiral out of your control quite quickly, but it functions. Kinda.

```
        #container {
                position:absolute;
                top:0;
                left:0;
                min-height:100%;
                width:90%;
                background-color:white;
        } 

        #green {
                min-height:100%;
                position:absolute;
                right:0;
                width:50%;
                background-color:green;
        }
```

The first place this example falls over is when you make the green box vastly bigger than the rest of your page content (which I've found can happen quite often).  Because you removed the parent from flow control and gave it a height based on the viewport, it **no longer calculates its height based on its children**, and the larger child overflows. Yuck.

One way to hack around this is to remove the responsibility of "scrolling" the page from your HTML element.  This has some special compatibility issues. It works sometimes!

```
        #container {
                position:absolute;
                top:0;
                overflow:auto;
                left:0;
                min-height:100%;
                width:100%;
                background-color:white;
        }
```

Generally speaking I don't find using absolute positioning for everything to be good enough. Absolute positioning removes elements from flow control, and I like to take advantage of standard flow control to keep my page elements from flowing underneath or ontop of each other.

One of my favourite filthy hacks at the moment looks like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/AvLQy/

```
<div id="h4x"></div>

<div id="content">
content
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
sidebar
</div>

#sidebar { 
    background:green;
    width:30%;
    float:right;
    position:relative; z-index:99;
}
#h4x {
    position:fixed;
    width:30%;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    height:100%;
    background:green;
    z-index:0;
}
```

Readers familiar with really old css hacks will notice that this is an ugly extension of faux columns.

It's ugly because it creates a spare html element.

But because it only involves pulling one element out of flow control, you don't have to worry about the effects of adding more content on a precarious interaction between childrens heights and positioned parents.

(*) sort of. read the spec for the full story